# Webpack-dev-server doesn't build files on change

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

So I have the following webpack configuration :

```
import path from 'path';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
    index: './dev/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: './dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        loader:{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude:path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            loader: 'js'
        }
    }

};
```

The problem is that when I do `webpack --watch`the file does build in the `/dist/` folder at every change. Yet when I run the `webpack-dev-server` the files don't even build. Why is that?

Please help.

Comment: But the changes _are_ reflected in your browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing files emitted into your dist folder is because webpack-dev-server uses an *in-memory filesystem*

This allows for extremely fast incremental builds when your code changes. This was an intentional design on our part. You can view the resulting code in your browser and never need to reference those files.

It is not recommended by us, for the sake of build performance, but you can look in to plugins like [write-file-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin) if you need this feature.

Answer (score 0):

'webpack' writes your bundle to disk, whereas 'webpack-dev-server' loads the bundle into memory. So when running the latter command you wont see a new 'bundle.js' file appear in your file system, even though you should see output to the console reporting the bundling and the start up of the dev server).

The output.publicPath config key determines the location of the in-memory bundle on the host dev server. So if you set the publicPath to 'dist' then the index.html served by the webpack dev server will need a script tag  in order to reference the bundle.